# RemoveLast node in linkedlist <e>

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

Hello I am creating a class in java that removes the last node in a list and returns the last node value. I am stuck and would  like some advice thank you.

```
 public E removeLast() {
  Node <E> prev=head;
  Node <E> curr=null;
  E last=null;
  while(prev != null ){
            last = prev.val;
            curr=prev;
            if (prev==null)
            {
                prev=curr;
                prev=null;
                size--;
                break;
            }
            prev=prev.next;
        }
return last;
}
```

Comment: What's the specific problem?

Comment: it does not delete the last node in the linkedlist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tri it :-

```
Current = head;
prev = null;
int ans =0;
while(current !=null){
     prev = current;
     current = current.next;
     if(current.next == null){
        prev.next = null
        ans = current.val;
        break;
     }
}
return ans;
```